# How to render a big list and still have perfomance

Tags: reactjs, performance, next.js

I've been building a "pokedex" as a side project, and what it does so far is basically render an big array of pokemons in a grid and display it on screen.

I knew that this was going to be a problem but since i didn't know how to "fix" that I ignored it, but now it's getting really lag when I try to refresh the page.

This is the base code for the whole grid of pokemons, but what i wanted to know is **how to make it paint only what I am seeing**, instead of loading all 900+~ cards of pokemon (some library or funcionality from react itself), if there is any tips to make the performance better please say so

```
<Grid
        templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)"
        width="50%"
        height="auto"
        padding="6"
        marginTop="6"
        marginBottom="6"
        gap="5"
        bg="white"
        borderRadius="3%"
      >
        {pokedex.map((poke) => (
          <Link
            href={{
              pathname: "/pokemon/[id]",
              query: {
                name: poke.name.english,
                id: poke.id,
                img: replace(poke.id),
                base: JSON.stringify(poke.base),
                type: poke.type,
              },
            }}
          >
            <Center>
              <Box
                className={styles.cardTranslateY}
                bg={bgColoursType(poke.type) || "#D9DFD8"}
                display="flex"
                flexDirection="column"
                borderRadius="20px"
                cursor="pointer"
                w="90%"
                height="100%"
                overflow="hidden"
                maxH="200px"
              >
                <Grid templateColumns="repeat(2, 1fr)">
                  <Box marginStart="4" marginTop="4" w="auto" h="auto">
                    <Text fontSize="2xl" color="white">
                      {poke.name.english}
                    </Text>
                    <Center
                      bg={bgColoursType(poke.type[0]) || "#D9DFD8"}
                      display="inline-block"
                      borderRadius="20%"
                      filter=" brightness(70%)"
                      mt=".2rem"
                      ms=".5rem"
                    >
                      <Text fontSize="lg" color="white" padding="5px">
                        {poke.type[0]}
                      </Text>
                    </Center>
                  </Box>
                  <Flex justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                    <Text
                      marginBottom="20px"
                      zIndex="xl"
                      fontSize="lg"
                      color="white"
                      fontWeight="bold"
                    >
                      #{poke.id}
                    </Text>
                  </Flex>
                </Grid>
                <Box
                  display="flex"
                  justifyContent="flex-end"
                  marginEnd="4"
                  w="auto"
                  h="auto"
                >
                  <Image
                    boxSize="auto"
                    objectFit="cover"
                    src="/pokeballwb.png"
                    position="relative"
                    left="180px"
                    top="-40px"
                    filter="opacity(30%)"
                  />
                  <Image
                    boxSize="100px"
                    objectFit="cover"
                    marginEnd="20px"
                    position="relative"
                    zIndex="1"
                    src={replace(poke.id)}
                    alt={poke.name.english}
                  />
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </Center>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at some of these popular packages that tackle your issue. You can find specific implementation described in their own docs as well.

[react-virtualized](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized)

[react-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-window)

[react-infinite-scroll-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component)

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look into these libs

Comment: I'm just going to add here that react-infinite-scroll-component did the job perfectly! I was not getting it at first but it worked out great, just like i wanted, thanks